# getting Error "URI formats are not supported."

Tags: c#, file

here i m trying to generate excel file and save this file to my local application folder but i m getting Error "URI formats are not supported.", can any one tell why i mgetting this

```
File.WriteAllText(ClsCommon.ApplicationPath + "TR_Temp/" + "AssessmentSheet.xls", renderedGridView);
```

Comment: Well what is `ClsCommon.ApplicationPath`?

Comment: Always use System.IO.Path.Combine() to create a path and filename.

Comment: ClsCommon.ApplicationPath give my local applcation path.its a comman class where i write property for application path

Comment: @Sandeep I think what Jon is asking is "Can you please post the value of ClsCommon.ApplicationPath at the point in time that the application crashes."

Comment: ita my local host path

Comment: I just want to create file and Save /TR-Temp folder which is in my application foldar

Comment: @SANDEEP, what Tarik,RB and Jon have meant write here the value of your ClsCommon.ApplicationPath like: C:\Users\...

Comment: http://localhost:1682/TR-WEB-Corp/

Comment: If `ClsCommon.ApplicationPath` dont return `/` after path, try `/TR_Temp/`

Comment: hi PiLHA i have try this also but it didnt work

Comment: @SANDEEP, so the exception you got clearly explains itself. URI formats are not supported. You need to use a filepath and no URI.

Comment: thats my question how can i can file path where i create my folder TR_Temp

Answer (score 1):

In the comments you mention that `ClsCommon.ApplicationPath` is `"localhost:1682/TR-WEB-Corp"`. That is, you are trying to write to a file with the path `"localhost:1682/TR-WEB-CorpTR_Temp/AssessmentSheet.xls"`.

This is not a path, but an URI. A path is something on a local or a network disk and should either start with a drive name (`C:`, `D:`, etc) or a network share name (`\\network\share`).

Also, your path seems to be missing a path separator (backslash) between `ClsCommon.ApplicationPath` and `"TR_Temp/"`. As mentioned by @Heslacher in the comments, it's a good idea to use `System.IO.Path.Combine()` to avoid these kind of bugs.

Answer (score 0):

Using the methods

```
System.IO.Path.GetTempPath()
System.IO.Path.Combine()
```

you can get a valid filename like:

```
string fileName = System.IO.Path.Combine(System.IO.Path.GetTempPath(), "TR_Temp","AssessmentSheet.xls");
File.WriteAllText(fileName, renderedGridView);
```

to write the content of renderedGridView to a file.
See: [System.IO.Path.Combine()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd784047%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) and [System.IO.Path.GetTempPath()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.gettemppath.aspx)